# vertical bar and null used for in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Hi I am new to JavaScript and TypeScript

That does this mean here on the code below

what is use for |?

and what is null = null used for?

```
let element: HTMLElement | null = null;
```

Comment: `|` is a union of types. It can be read as 'or'. So here it's saying `element` can be of type HTMLElement *or* null, and it currently has a value of null.

Comment: I heavily recommend you learn the basics of TS. [The TS handbook should be a good introduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.htmll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let element: HTMLElement | null = null;
// Equivalent to
let element: (HTMLElement | null) = null;
```

`|` means make a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), which means the variable can be any of the types listed.

This code means:

- Create a variable, called `element`,
- that can either be of the type `HTMLElement` OR `null` (nothing),
- and set its initial value to `null` (nothing).

Answer (score 0):

It defines a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

The value of `element` can be either of the type `HTMLElement` or the type `null`.

Note that `HTMLElement | null` is the type and that `= null` is the assignment. It is not `null = null`.

---

You could rewrite this as:

```
type PossibleHTMLElement = HTMLElement | null;
let element: PossibleHTMLElement = null;
```

Which might be clearer.